# Visual Basic 2013 create new Record in Access Execure Error

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, records

I am creating a simple UserID/Password access database for a Visual Basic program.
Everything works except adding a new user.

My text box Objects are linked to my database but I keep getting this error when I try to add my new user.

[image: Screen grab of Error window at .ExecuteNonQuery()]

> Error: An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class newUser

    Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\PasswordCheck.accdb"
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection


    Private Sub btnNewUser_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNewUser.Click


        Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\PasswordCheck.accdb"
        Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection


        conn.ConnectionString = connString

        conn.Open()

        Dim SaveNew As String = "INSERT INTO [Password] (UserId, Password, firstName, LastName) Values ('" & txtUserID.Text & "','" & txtPassword.Text & "','" & txtFirst.Text & "','" & txtLast.Text & "')"
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        cmd.Connection = conn

        With cmd
            .CommandText = SaveNew
            .Connection = conn
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        MsgBox("You have been added to our Database")
        txtUserID.Text = ""
        txtPassword.Text = ""
        txtFirst.Text = ""
        txtLast.Text = ""
        conn.Close()

    End Sub



    Private Function SaveNew() As String
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: A) that is a VB.NET code/error not VB6 so the Tag is wrong, b) we need the text of the error IN the post, not a link to a picture of an error c) there is more info in details d) **Never** concat strings to make SQL; use sql Parameters e) passwords should never be stored as plain text - hash them. f) read [ask], take the [tour], fix the tag and [edit] the post please

Comment: I agree with everything that Plutonix said. But if you insist on using string concatenation, you are missing the commas between the variables

Comment: I have changed the tag, and added the commas. I still get the error.

Comment: text of error included.

Comment: "use sql Parameters e) passwords should never be stored as plain text - hash them." As a novice to VB can you direct me to an example?

Comment: So you can't help me. Clearly I have been searching online and have resorted to ask for help. Sorry to have bothered you all.

Answer (score 0):

*Password* is a reserved word also for a field, so:

```
Dim SaveNew As String = "INSERT INTO [Password] (UserId, [Password], FirstName, LastName) Values ('" & txtUserID.Text & "','" & txtPassword.Text & "','" & txtFirst.Text & "','" & txtLast.Text & "')"
```

And further, if *UserID* not is text, then no quotes:

```
Dim SaveNew As String = "INSERT INTO [Password] (UserId, [Password], FirstName, LastName) Values (" & txtUserID.Text & ",'" & txtPassword.Text & "','" & txtFirst.Text & "','" & txtLast.Text & "')"
```

That said, try to explorer how to carry this out using *parameters*. Much more fun than SQL concatenation.

Comment: AH HUH! OK. Thanks, Gustav. I willtry again with differnt field names. Unfortunatetly I have not found an example using parameters. Do you mean something like this?                                                                        
 Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Passwords] WHERE [userID] = '" & txtUserID.Text & "' AND [Password] = '" & txtPassword.Text & "'", myConnection)

Comment: No. It's like this: [OleDb Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924636/oledb-parameters/21924799#21924799). But - as someone already told you in his own polite way - if you browse a little, you'll find numerous examples and guides. I don't use the OleDb stuff myself; I prefer to use the _DataTableAdapter_ but that's another story.