# How to search between 2 dates on access database vs?

Tags: c#

I'm trying this code but it shows an error on `da.Fill(dt)`

`No value given for one or more required parameters.`

Why does it show that error? I clearly check all names of databases and tables and fields, they all are correct and I'm using date/time field for datetime.

Can you help me with this?

```
     string conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ahmed\OneDrive\Documents\shop.accdb";
       OleDbConnection ccc = new OleDbConnection(conn);
        ccc.Open();
        string css = "SELECT * from tbl3 Where dateitem between '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + "%' AND '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString()+"%'";
        OleDbCommand non = new OleDbCommand(css, ccc);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(non);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        count = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
        dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource(dt, null);
```

Comment: use parameters instead baking SQL by yourself

Comment: That is not how to query a database. You need to [use parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924636/).

Comment: ... and pass dates as dates not as strings.

Comment: Can your db use % in a date string?!

Comment: yes it can use % i tried that but same error

Comment: @BestMovies copy the query `SELECT * FROM tbl3 ..` in a string "once it was created" and paste such query in your database.

Comment: Calling ExecuteNonQuery should not be required - that is for Update/Delete/Insert SQL commands.

Comment: Can you show exactly what your query string is.

Comment: have you tried changing the date format? (yyyy/MM/dd)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OleDB Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924636/oledb-parameters)

Comment: no, I need to do it in same my code

Comment: and how I use parameters I'm kinda new to c#

Comment: any help?......

Comment: Previous comments include links that answer your question. Did you try clicking on them? What happened when you tried to follow the answers?

Comment: I want an example I don't know what parameters I should use

Comment: I just edit the code that I tried but it shows an error on `da.Fill(dt);` error = (No value given for one or more required parameters.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned you should use the parameters instead of hard coding the values.

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ahmed\OneDrive\Documents\shop.accdb"))
{
    conn.Open();
    // DbCommand also implements IDisposable
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        var param1 = new OleDbParameter("@DateTimePicker1", OleDbType.DBDate); //you may have to play with different types
        param1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

        var param2 = new OleDbParameter("@DateTimePicker2", OleDbType.DBDate);
        param2.Value = dateTimePicker2.Value;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from tbl3 Where datetime >= @DateTimePicker1 and datetime <= @DateTimePicker2";

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        count = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
        dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource(dt, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: there is an error on `OleDbConnection ccc = new OleDbConnection(conn);`

Comment: Please see the updated code.  You no longer need the `OleDbConnection ccc = new OleDbConnection(conn);`

Comment: thanks, I tried that this code seems awsome but the error after pressing the button on `ds.Fill(dt);`  =  No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: I set the format of DateTimePicker to long and on access DB I set on design view to long as well

Comment: My apologies.  Please see the latest updated code.  If it does not work make sure you can open the tbl3 in access without access requesting you to an input.
*Edit* Also make sure your dateTimePicker1 and dateTimePicker2 have value.

Comment: I tried this on ur code and it worked   `cmd.CommandText = "select * from tbl3 where datetime >= @DateTimePicker1 and datetime <= @DateTimePicker2";`